# Creating a measure by filtering out a set from an existing measure

Tags: mdx, measure

I am trying to implement something as follows:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.Test2 AS 
Sum
(
  {
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2006]
   ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
  }
 ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
) 
SELECT Measures.Test2 ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

But i want the new measure Test2 to be sliceable according to the Calendar Year dimension. So i want something like

```
SELECT {Measures.Test2} ON 0,
{[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS} ON 1 
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This is giving the same value for both the years 2006 and 2007.

In essence i want to create a member by taking a subset of an existing measure and then using it for further calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is not valid `mdx`:

```
SELECT (Measures.Test2,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year] ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

You have a single `(` before Measures.
Also you look like you're about to add a `tuple` ON COLUMNS which is not allowed. Only sets are allowed on rows and columns:

```
SELECT 
{Measures.Test2} ON 0,
{[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Try the following:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER Measures.Test2 AS 
    Sum
    (
      Intersect
      (
        {[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember}
       ,{
          [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2006]
         ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
        }
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].test2 ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The above returns this:

[image]

Or maybe all you want is a `subselect`:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
      [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2006]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
    } ON 0
  FROM [Adventure Works]
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have edited the query. i ran the query u gave i am getting same value for all the years. I want it such that i can see the data for years individually as well. So I want the data for all years except 2006 and 2007 to be 0 and 2006 and 2007 should also have their unique values.

Comment: @Shashank I added a possible amendment